# Using data from PHP input in a variable

Tags: php, html, input, handle

So i'm trying to set the variable "String" to the value of the input but i can't seem to figure it out.... here is the code:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">

<?php
$string =  $_GET["name"];
$string2 = "example.com";
$image = imageCreateFromPng("http://i.imgur.com/2AKemxI.png");
$cor = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$background = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($image, $background);
imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
imagestring($image,5,110,22,urldecode($string),$cor);
imagestring($image,5,110,53,urldecode($string2),$cor);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image,NULL);
?>
```

I am probably making a lot of mistakes there, i just recently started to work with php
Thanks!

Comment: So, what's not working, errors if any, checking for errors...? Form is properly syntaxed. Can be 1 of many things.

Comment: The code suggests you are trying to do this inline, as if this were javascript.  Is this the case (this is in one file as you listed here?) or are we missing other code, as @Fred-ii- asks you to provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You learning, so try to send your get information from other page. Someone like:

form.html

```
<form method="get" action="imagecreate.php">
<input type="text" name="name" value="">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

imagecreate.php

```
<?php
  $im = imageCreateFromPng("teste.png");

  $cor = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
  $background = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
  imagecolortransparent($im, $background);
  imagealphablending($im, false);

  // display string
  imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $_GET['name'], $cor);

  // print image
  header("Content-type: image/png");
  imagepng($im);
}
```

When you define a header, no information outside the defined type must be displayed in the script

Answer (score 0):

First, you're usign the `header('Content-type: image/png');` after a html tag (the input), header function must always been called before any html... You should put your input in an other page, in a proper form, that call the page containing your php

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said, your question is a little scares.

That being said, (this might be thinking in to simple terms, excuse me if it is) are you posting or getting your form. Cause if your form looks like this:

```
<form action="url" method="post">
```

You should use the `$_POST`